# Intellij not asking whether to open project in same window or different window

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have intellij CE 13. When I try to open recent project it does not ask whether to open project in same window or different window. How do I enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

I made some screenshots because pictures say more than words:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see any Settings section under File menu. There is Other Setting under File menu and in the Default Settings I dont see any settings for "Project Opening"

Comment: @PrathikPuthran Try [Crtl]+[Alt]+[S] maybe?

Comment: I'm using MAC OS. The views must be different I believe. Let me try this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on IntelliJ IDEA 15 or higher, go to `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings` and choose your option under `Project Opening`.

[image: Intellij IDEA 15 OSX Project Opening Dialog Settings]